# How to check permissions associated with a specific IAM access key in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

Is there way to check which permissions or roles are associated with a specific AWS access key?

The problem is that I got a pair of keys working but they are not present in the AWS console.  These key are used regularly from some internal process but I cannot find which one.

If I search for them in the console they don't appear and neither on the root account.

Comment: Do you have access key + secret key (from IAM), or access key + secret key + session token (from STS)?

Answer (score 1):

You can search for the user by Access key ID in the AWS console.
See this blog post for details and screenshots:

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/introducing-iam-console-search/

Don't forget, that according to the blog post

> ... you must type the full access key ID when searching.

Answer (score 0):

In the end I wasn't able to get the roles or policies associate with a specific user, but I was able to track down the user.
So the user was using the **root credentials** and since I am using a *normal* full administrator account I wasn't able to see these creds even on the console 
Pretty scary thing :|